# SWIFT - Append Int to array in NSUser Default Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, append, nsuserdefaults

I have a `NSUserDefault` dictionary. One of the keys has a value of type `[Int]`. I'm looking to figure out how to append `Ints` to that embedded array.

```
var dictionary = ["keyOne" : [1,2,3,4,5]]
defaults.setObject(dictionary, forKey: "defaultDictionary")
```

What I'm currently doing is saving the dictionary to a variable, creating a variable array from the new dictionary variable and then appending that. Then I'm updating the dictionary with the new array and saving that dictionary back to the defaults.

Does anyone out there know of a direct way to append to the array without having to do all the middle work?

Comment: fasik, I don't think you can. You can only set and get things from nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
func saveArray(valueArray: [AnyObject], key: String) {
    let dataToSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(valueArray)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dataToSave, forKey: key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed property and define getter/setter to save it automatically to user defaults. You will need to cast from [String:[Int]] to [String:AnyObject] to be able to save it to NSUSerDefaults:

```
var defaultDictionary:[String:[Int]] {
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("defaultDictionary") as? [String:[Int]] ??  [:]
    }
    set {
        NSUserDefaults().setObject(newValue as [String:AnyObject], forKey: "defaultDictionary")
    }
}


print(defaultDictionary["keyOne"]?.description ?? "")  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(defaultDictionary["keyTwo"]?.description ?? "")  // [1, 2, 3]

defaultDictionary["keyOne"]?.append(6)
defaultDictionary["keyTwo"]?.append(4)

print(defaultDictionary["keyOne"]?.description ?? "")  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(defaultDictionary["keyTwo"]?.description ?? "")  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It is not working on playGround but it is working in real project.. why?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read and write objects from `NSUserDefaults`. If you use it often write some methods e.g:

```
func updateDefaultsWithArray(array: [Int]) {
    let dictionary = ["keyOne" : array]
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(dictionary, forKey: "defaultDictionary")
}
```